# ConcurrentModification exception in java

Tags: java

When I try to modify a collection while iterating through it, will result in ConcurrentModification exception (i.e., when using forEach and forEachRemaining)

But below code won't why?

```
List<String> list=new  ArrayList<>();  

list.add("ram");
list.add("ravi");
Iterator<String> it=list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  System.out.printing(it.next());
 it.remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you put the actual code here? Your code is not even valid.

Comment: Because it is not modifying the list (!)

Comment: @texasbruce the first line of the op is: "When I try to modify a collection while iterating through it"

Comment: @p.streef - Yes.  We see that.  He **thinks** he is modifying the list, but clearly, he isn't!

Comment: @StephenC please read the entire question...

Comment: @p.streef I was confused about his english here.

Comment: @p.streef  I did.  Did you??  He is asking for an explanation of why his code ins not thowing a CCME

Comment: If I do A, I get an exception. However, if I do B (see code) it does not. Why? So while it might be the inverse of the duplicate question. I think it will do.....

Comment: And the answer is because in B ... you are not doing A.  The inverse of a Q doesn't generally answer another one ... when the OP is clearly not "getting it".  As in this case.

Comment: That is a bit literal, but you are right I guess. I do think the OP might have more use of reading the duplicate though.

Comment: @texasbruce sorry now I edited it

Comment: Now your question makes sense. It does not throw that exception because operations on iterators are deemed safe - it is internally modifying all the necessary components. Meanwhile modifying a collection directly in a loop is not deemed safe. You can take a look at this: http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/04/fail-fast-iterator-vs-fail-safe-iterator-difference-with-example-in-java.html?m=1

Comment: @StephenC actually just before I modified my question, can you change your answer

Comment: I already have.  Read it.

Answer (score -1):

You ask why

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printing(it.next());
}
```

does not throw a CCME.

The answer is simple.  A CCME is thrown if you modify a list while iterating it.  You are iterating the list, but you are not modifying it at the same time.  Therefore the condition for throwing a CCME is *not satisfied*.

(The same reasoning applies in the case of a non-empty list too ...)

---

Let me break it down for you.  You said:

> When I try to modify a collection while iterating through it, will result in ConcurrentModification exception.

(This is correct as a general statement, by the way.  But not universally.)

Reducing that to simple propositional logic we get:

```
exception_thrown = iterating_collection AND modifying_collection
```

In your example

```
iterating_collection is TRUE

modifying_collection is FALSE
```

but

```
TRUE AND FALSE is FALSE
```

therefore

```
exception_thrown is FALSE
```

In English, CCME is not thrown.

---

Now for your updated code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  
list.add("ram");
list.add("ravi");
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printing(it.next());
    it.remove();
}
```

In this case, you are modifying the collection **using the iterator**.  This is the one situation where you are *allowed* to modify a collection while iterating it.

Think about it.  If `Iterator.remove()` was not permitted to remove an element from the collection that is being iterated, it would be a fundamentally useless operation!

Comment: but using forEachRemaining you can't do Iterator.remove.why?

Comment: Huh?  If you are in a `forEachRemaining` call, you don't have access to the iterator.  Show me what you mean.

Comment: I mean CCME will occur when you use iterator.remove inside forEachRemaining of the same iterator.why so?

Comment: it.forEachRemaining( data -> { System.out.println(data);                  it.remove();} this is the scenario bro

Comment: That's not a CCME.  It is an IllegalStateException.

Comment: Sorry for that, then why can't we modify that collection.

Comment: The `forEachRemaining` javadoc (Java 9) says: *"The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the action modifies the collection in any way **(even by calling the remove method or other mutator methods of Iterator subtypes)**, unless an overriding class has specified a concurrent modification policy."*  Link:  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: Thanks a lot  bro

Comment: Please explain the downvote.